# "rails server" not seeing rails project locally which works fine on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am new to rails and just created simple "empty" app in heroku and synchronized that with my dropbox account. I was able to open heroku site in web browser, then I changed index.rb and deployed the application and changes was **done correctly**, I saw the result in web browser.

So the application in dropbox folder works correctly BUT I am not able to run it locally. When I type rails server in project folder it just not recognized the project and gave me:

```
C:\Users\Dav\Dropbox\Apps\Heroku\aqueous-waters-4632>rails server
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby bina
ry of your choice
                                                         # Default: C:/RailsInst
aller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some applicat
ion template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfil
e
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle inst
all
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .
keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record fi
les
  -V, [--skip-action-view], [--no-skip-action-view]      # Skip Action View file
s
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring
application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for sele
cted database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserv
er/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for sele
cted JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files

      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application
 with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application
 with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files

      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containi
ng extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra
 configuration options from .railsrc file

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

**These are my Ruby and Rails versions(Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.1.8):**

```
C:\Users\Dav\Dropbox\Apps\Heroku\aqueous-waters-4632>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\Dav\Dropbox\Apps\Heroku\aqueous-waters-4632>rails -v
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Rails 4.1.8

C:\Users\Dav\Dropbox\Apps\Heroku\aqueous-waters-4632>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.11.2)
jar-dependencies (0.1.15)
jruby-openssl (0.9.7 java)
jruby-win32ole (0.8.5)
json (1.8.0 java)
minitest (5.4.1)
power_assert (0.2.3)
psych (2.0.14.pre1 java)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
ruby-maven (3.3.3)
ruby-maven-libs (3.3.3)
test-unit (3.0.3)
```

**and finally this is heroku build log for reference(Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.1.8):**

```
-----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby

-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.2-jruby-9.0.0.0

-----> Installing JVM: openjdk-8

-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7

       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment

       Using json 1.8.1

       Using minitest 5.4.3

       Using thread_safe 0.3.4

       Using builder 3.2.2

       Using erubis 2.7.0

       Using rake 10.4.0

       Using rack 1.5.2

       Using i18n 0.6.11

       Using mime-types 2.4.3

       Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214

       Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0

       Using jdbc-postgres 9.3.1102

       Using execjs 2.2.2

       Using thor 0.19.1

       Using hike 1.2.3

       Using multi_json 1.10.1

       Using bundler 1.9.7

       Using tilt 1.4.1

       Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2

       Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3

       Using sass 3.2.19

       Using tzinfo 1.2.2

       Using rdoc 4.1.2

       Using mail 2.6.3

       Using rack-test 0.6.2

       Using puma 2.9.1

       Using coffee-script 2.3.0

       Using uglifier 2.5.3

       Using rails_12factor 0.0.3

       Using sprockets 2.12.3

       Using activesupport 4.1.8

       Using tzinfo-data 1.2015.1

       Using sdoc 0.4.1

       Using actionview 4.1.8

       Using activemodel 4.1.8

       Using jbuilder 2.2.5

       Using actionpack 4.1.8

       Using activerecord 4.1.8

       Using actionmailer 4.1.8

       Using sprockets-rails 2.2.2

       Using railties 4.1.8

       Using activerecord-jdbc-adapter 1.3.14

       Using activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter 1.3.14

       Using coffee-rails 4.0.1

       Using jquery-rails 3.1.2

       Using rails 4.1.8

       Using sass-rails 4.0.5

       Using turbolinks 2.5.2

       Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 48 gems now installed.

       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.

       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.

       Bundle completed (8.97s)

       Cleaning up the bundler cache.

-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline

       Running: rake assets:precompile

       Asset precompilation completed (13.25s)

       Cleaning assets

       Running: rake assets:clean

-----> Discovering process types

       Procfile declares types     -> web

       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, worker

-----> Compressing...

       Done: 101.5M

-----> Launching...

       Released v8
```

Comment: try running `bundle install` and then `rails server`

Comment: You can try `bundle exec rails s` or `bin\rails s`

Comment: Thanks for reply's but none of this is working

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `bundle install` to install your gems, go to db/migrate and run `rake db:migrate` and then `rails s`.

Comment: I am getting
C:\Users\Dav\Dropbox\Apps\Heroku\aqueous-waters-4632\db\migrate>rake db:migrate
(in C:/Users/Dav/Dropbox/Apps/Heroku/aqueous-waters-4632)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused.
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is acceptin
g TCP/IP connections.
arjdbc/jdbc/RubyJdbcConnection.java:453:in `init_connection'
c:\jruby-9.0.0.0\bin\rake:23:in `<top>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Do you have a line like this `validate_presence_of :something` in one of your controllers ?

Comment: No, there is no such thing in project